# Replace text in a Visual Studio Code Snippet Literal

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets

Is it possible to replace text in a Visual Studio Snippet literal after the enter key is pressed and the snippet exits its edit mode?

For example, given a snippet like this:

```
 public void $name$
 {
   $end$
 }
```

If I were to enter $name$ as:

```
 My function name
```

is it possible to have Visual Studio change it to:

```
 My_function_name
```

or

```
 MyFunctionName
```

Comment: There are only four functions available while inserting code snippet. Currently there is no option to create
user defined functions.
three of them - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242312.aspx
Callbase -  Returns a call to the base member, or returns a NotImplementedException if the member is abstract.

Comment: You should answer this in an answer so it can be voted on and accepted.

Comment: Snippet functionality is very limited. It's just text insert.  After many years, VS did not add needed basic string manipulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many years there is an answer, for anyone still coming across this question:

```
"Replace Whitespaces": {
    "prefix": "wrap2",
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/[' ']/_/gi}",
    ],
    "description": "Replace all whitespaces of highlighted Text with underscores"
},
```

Add this to your user snippets. Or alternativly you can add a keyboard shortcut like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+y",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/[' ']/_/gi}"            
    }
},
```

Hope this helps anyone coming across this in the future

Comment: This is awesome!  If you selected some text like **' te'xt '**, could you use this to replace the *outermost* single quotes with double quotes?

Comment: @Tedskovsky Probably - the replacement in the snippet part is just a RegEx. As I only know my basic ways around RegEx-Magic (it definitely is magic), maybe try asking this in a seperate question.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the goal was to replace a single instance of the word `Authoring` with `Baker`:

```
${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(Authoring)/Baker/}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's great. I used it to wrap things in a function with quotes. If a selection has quotes it can remove the quotes. In the snippet part, it seems to break down into:

```
TM_SELECTED_TEXT - this is the input
[ ' '] - regex find
_ - regex replace
gi - global flag for regex
```

So what I wanted is change: `"User logged in"` into: `<%= gettext("User logged in") %>`
For this in the snippet I used:

```
"body": ["<%= gettext(\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/['\"']//gi}\") %>"],
```

Note: you need to escape the quotein the regular expression, therefore: " becomes \".